# OpenAI turbo-3.5 API returning error with complex prompts

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api, chatgpt-api

With simple prompts like "Hey" or "Tell me [this]" or "Summarize [this]", it works fine. But when I run more complex prompts like "List this and that and explain...", it breaks. There's no other change besides the complexity. The error message:
`APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))`

I'm running this on JupyterLab.

I'd really appreciate help.

```py
def get_completion(prompt, model="gpt-3.5-turbo"):
    messages = [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model=model,
        messages=messages,
        temperature=0,
    )
    return response.choices[0].message["content"]
```

Comment: As the error message says, this is a _remote_ problem; you need to talk to the people who run the server; it's not an issue with the client.

Comment: (It's possible that what you have is actually a network issue like a TCP keepalive timeout problem, but that's a question for your network engineering team -- who will be able to monitor the network connection as it leaves your organization's perimeter and see which side the RST is coming from -- not for us).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you, Charles, for the comment. I tried without my VPN. It worked.